# Calculate time ago using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say i've the following table `test` and it has columns `id`, `time`, `post` and this is a sample of the data it has.

```
-----------------------------------
   id           time        post
-----------------------------------     
    1   2018-06-17 16:12:30 post1
    2   2018-06-17 16:13:09 post2
    3   2017-06-15 16:12:30 post7
----------------------------------
```

I want to print out using only `SQL` how many Days,hours,minutes and seconds ago since each post has been added to the database

Okay, here is my first try

```
SELECT
    id,
    time,
    NOW(),
    CONCAT (
    FLOOR(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(NOW() - `time`), '%H') / 24),
    ' Days ',
    MOD (TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(NOW() - `time`), '%H'), 24),
    ' Hours ',
    TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(NOW() - `time`), '%i Minutes %s Seconds'),
    ' ago' 
    ) AS `ago` 
FROM
    `test`;
```

but it seems it does not giving correct calculations, For example the output of the sample above was

```
1   2018-06-17 16:12:30 2018-06-17 20:38:08 0 Days 11 Hours 49 Minutes 38 Seconds ago
2   2018-06-17 16:13:09 2018-06-17 20:38:08 0 Days 11 Hours 48 Minutes 19 Seconds ago
3   2017-06-15 16:12:30 2018-06-17 20:38:08 34 Days 22 Hours 59 Minutes 59 Seconds ago
```

as you can see, in `id = 3` however the difference should be more not only `34` days as it print out

so what is wrong with the code ?! ~ thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this query. Calculating the intervals by `TIMESTAMPDIFF` and `TIMESTAMPADD` function.

```
SELECT
    id,
    time,
    NOW(),
    CONCAT (
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,`time`, NOW()),' Days ',
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `time`, NOW()), `time`), NOW()),' Hours ',
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `time`, NOW()), `time`), NOW()), ' Minutes ',
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `time`, NOW()), `time`), NOW()), ' Seconds '
    ' ago' ) AS `ago` 
FROM
    `test`;
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e8085/2

**NOTE**

For example, you want to get Interval on `SECOND`

let us step by step to know it:

1.`TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, time, NOW())` get Interval `MINUTE`  between `time` and `NOW()`

2.`TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, time, NOW()), time)` append Interval `MINUTE` to `time`, let them only have Interval time on `second`.

3.Calculating intervals on second.

Comment: It works perfect, however it looks very complex to my mind :) but i will study it piece by piece .. thanks a lot for sharing

Comment: @RehamFahmy No problem :),

Comment: The logic of this statement is setting a time base and Calculate your expected type of time

Comment: @RehamFahmy I add some note wish can help you

Comment: thanks, I've understood the point of view and i really liked a lot how you are doing a combination of different time related functions of SQL to do calculations .. i will definitely join in this summer SQL course to charge my knowledge more .. again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You may use TIMESTAMPDIFF with DATE_ADD for the missing parts( *year* and *month* ) of your query :

```
SELECT CONCAT (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, `time`, NOW()),' Year ',
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, DATE_ADD(`time`, 
                        INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, `time`, NOW()) YEAR), NOW()),
           ' Month ') as "Time(Year|Month)"
 FROM `test`;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/556c88/11)

Comment: this is perfect idea as well ~ thanks a lot for sharing